# eloquent refer to a column of a related a model

Tags: eloquent

I have three tables:

```
categories
id, title

products
id, name

categories_products
id, category_id, product_id
```

I have also setup the according models and relationships (both have belongsToMany of the other)

Now I want to get all products belonging to a category

```
Category::where('title','Electronics')->first()->products()->limit(10)->get(['products.name']);
```

which works fine, but I also want to include the category title for each product as well:

```
Category::where('title','Electronics')->first()->products()->limit(10)->get(['products.name','category.title']);
```

However it returns: Column not found category.title

I thought that the relation would take care of it.

EDIT: Models -->

Category:

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = array('title');

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'categories_products', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'categories_products', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relations on each model?

Comment: It looks like you're referencing `name` on `categories` but `name` is on `products`?

Comment: @EricTucker added and fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because `get()` works just like `select()` and because you're running the category query and then running the product query after there is no categories table to reference for the select.

Look into [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).  It will help with a lot of these kinds of issues.  Your query can be written as:

```
Product::select('id', 'name')
->with(['categories' => function($query) {
    return $query->select('id', 'title');
}])
->whereHas('categories', function($query) {
    return $query->where('title', 'Electronics');
})
->limit(10)
->get();
```

Because we are lazy loading you NEED the `id` column on each model so Laravel knows where to attach the relationships after the queries are run.

The `with()` method above will eager load the `categories` relationship and the `whereHas()` method puts a relationship constraint on the current query.

**UPDATE**

Similar query from `Category` model:

```
$category = Category::where('title','Electronics')
    ->with(['products' => function($query) {
        return $query->select('id', 'name')->limit(10);
    }])
    ->first(['id', 'title']);
```

Then access the products with:

```
$category->products
```

Comment: The important thing was the query withing the with function. It can be even tidier when starting the entire query from Category::

Comment: Ahhh, Updated the answer to query from category instead if that's what you're looking for